# JSON web services issue when Invalid Login

Tags: android, android-intent

I have JSON web services, node name of web services is change when valid and invalid login.

I have written code of valid web services. Now when invalid login at that time node name change , SO **How to identify valid and invalid authentication ?**

valid login

```
{
root: [
{
Login: {
uid: "1",
uname: "aaa",
email: "aaa@far.com",
}
}
]
}
```

invalid login

```
{
root: [
{
Result: {
Result: "Login failed"
}
}
]
}
```

Code is working when valid login , **my problem is that when invalid login at that how to check** ?

Becuase node name is change from "Login" to "Result"

```
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.e("log_tag", "root :" + result.toString());

        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);

        String root = json_data.getString("root");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), root, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(root);

        json_data = json_array.getJSONObject(0);

        String Login = json_data.getString("Login");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        json_data = new JSONObject(Login);

        String email = json_data.getString("email");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse and read the result this way:

```
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject root = json_data.getJSONArray("root").getJSONObject(0);
if (root.has("Result")) {
    JSONObject loginRes = root.getJSONObject("Result");
    if (loginRes.has("Result")) {
         String status = loginRes.getString("Result");
         if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Login failed")) {
             // LOGIN FAILED!
         }
    }
}
```

Note: your JSON seems poorly (logically) formatted, and contains some unnecessary items. You may want to simplify it.

Comment: which item is unnecessary  ?

Comment: `root` does not need to be an array, since it has only one item; in the second case, you have 2 nested `Result`, etc.